# Deleting Duplicate element in array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, element

```
public void noDups() {
    int rem = nElems;
    for (int t = 0; t < nElems; t++) {
        for (int t2 = 1; t2 < rem; t2++) {
            long mydup = a[t];
            long mydup2 = a[t+1];
            if (mydup == mydup2) {
                delete(mydup);
            }
        }
        rem--;
    }
}
public void delete(long value)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)        // look for it
        if( value == a[j] )
            break;
    else                           // found it
    {
        for(int k=j; k<nElems; k++) // move higher ones down
            a[k] = a[k+1];
        nElems--;                   // decrement size
        //return true;
    }
```

HOW do I add a method called noDups() that
removes duplicates from a previously sorted array without disrupting the order.
Note: Assume only one value in the array can have duplicates. For example, in
{1,3,4,4,4,4,5,7,9} only 4 has duplicates.

Comment: Good luck with getting an answer by only copy-pasting the requirement for the assignment.

Comment: @SklogW this is my code that i tried and i can't get it to do what i need so do you have any advice beside criticizing my assignment requirement

Comment: You already have a method _a method called noDups()_. You should review your question and add details about your concrete problem.

Comment: my method isn't working, i am unsure of what i am doing wrong any help? @MPirious

Comment: All these comments are to determine what `my method isn't working` means. What are you seeing, compared to what you'd like to be seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I've noticed:

-You have two `for` loops under `noDups`, but the variable `t2` isn't being used.

-You relocate all the items in the array, but the array will have the same length.

-Without running the code I'd guess you're seeing an `Array Index out of range` error due to `k+1` in the `else` portion of `delete`

Answer (score -1):

May be you try use ArrayList for yours solution...

See:

```
//for initialize
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();

    //for add a new number
    list.add(10l);

    //for remove
    list.remove(10l);

    //for verify if exists
    list.contains(10l);
```